# A consequence of the comprehension schema is that the intersection of two sets is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am currently doing a project on set theory and at the minute i am studying ZF axioms. A consequence of the comprehension schema is that the intersection of two sets is a set. Hnece i have come up with the following proporsition.

> Proposition: Let $x$ and $y$ be two sets. Then the intersection of $x$ and $y$, $x\cap y$ is a set.
>
> Proof: Define $P(z) = z \in Y$. Then  $x\cap y = \{ z \in x \wedge P(z)\} =\{ z \in x \wedge z \in y \}$. Hence, by the comprehension schema  $x\cap y$ is a set.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could let me know if there are any mistakes in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes not only is your proof correct for the intersection of two sets but with a minor adjustment you can prove it for any non empty class of sets (defined by a first order formula). This is intuitively true because the intersection is a subset of any of the sets partaking the intersection. The way you prove it is similar. Given a class (a collection of sets that may or may not be a set itself) defined by the formula $\varphi(x)$ then we can choose a set $a$ in the class (this is where you need it to be non empty) and we define the intersection to be $\{x\in a:\forall y (\varphi(y)\rightarrow x\in y)\}$ The new first order formula which uses comprehension is now $\psi(x)\equiv \forall y (\varphi(y)\rightarrow x\in y)$.